# Equivalent WCF config needed for these program lines

Tags: wcf, configuration, app-config, wcf-client, mtom

I am struggling at the moment to come up with the right config for a Web Service client build via WCF / Service Reference. I was able to create the binding and configure the endpoint programmatically, but ideally I would like these settings to go into a WCF config file. However I am not sure how to define the customer binding in there that would match the following settings (I have left out the more detailed settings for the mtom and https part...):

```
    Dim mtom As MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement =
        New MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8)

    Dim https As HttpsTransportBindingElement = New HttpsTransportBindingElement()

    Dim binding As CustomBinding = New CustomBinding()
    binding.Elements.Add(mtom)
    binding.Elements.Add(https)

    client.Endpoint.Binding = binding
```

I know that I need the customBinding element and refer to the element in the client section, but I can't seem to get the custom binding working as in the code above. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent custom binding in config is shown below.

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="SO_12399887">
    <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8" />
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```